# Why Eclipse is not displaying some of Android activity templates

Tags: android, eclipse, templates, authentication, wizard

When I want to create new activity with using loginactivity template, I can't see login activity template on eclipse list.

Here is my ..\sdk\tools\templates\activities folders image;

[image]

and here is my eclipse wizard window image;

[image]

How can eclipse display all activities on folder ? Thanks..